# Activity - custom date format display incorrect

Tags: civicase, activity, date-preferences

I've added a date and time field to an activity ('departure date'). The problem is that it steadfastly refuses to display as anything other than YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS even though the custom field is specified as d MM yy with a 12 hour time format. This is when I hit 'View' against an activity in a list of case activities and get a pop up. Which does look odd when the activity date is displayed correctly as (e.g.) 14 June, 2021 1:03pm. My 'date preferences' were all set to default (I'm in the UK) but to try and fix this this I've set the 2 activity dates formats to d MM yy, and the custome the same.  But to no avail.  Civi is at 5.37.2 - I guess a bug?
Problem raised as [this issue](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2655)

Comment: display 'where'?

Comment: only asking as there is an outstanding issue of time/date not displaying in specified format in eg receipts

Comment: Edited the question & added 'This is when I hit 'View' against an activity in a list of case activities & get a pop up'

Comment: I can see the same problem on other activity types too where there is a custom date field. The activity date shows up as d MM y but the custom date is dd/mm/yyy (where there is no time field)

Comment: is it the same outcome if you right click and open as new tab? (just to confirm it isn't pop-up only behaviour?)

Comment: It's the same problem in a new tab

Comment: I see the same thing just haven't noticed since my date setting actually is yyyy-mm-dd. I'd post a lab ticket.

Answer (score 1):

This is specific to civicase activities and it's because the view form uses its own way of displaying custom fields that's different from regular activities. I posted this quickie patch in the lab ticket but it's not the best long-term solution:

```
diff --git a/templates/CRM/Case/Form/ActivityView.tpl b/templates/CRM/Case/Form/ActivityView.tpl
index 9bc3c3d781..868c69c512 100644
--- a/templates/CRM/Case/Form/ActivityView.tpl
+++ b/templates/CRM/Case/Form/ActivityView.tpl
@@ -54,7 +54,11 @@
             {foreach from=$customGroup item=customField name=fields}
               <tr{if ! $smarty.foreach.fields.last} style="border-bottom: 1px solid #F6F6F6;"{/if}>
                 <td class="label">{$customField.label}</td>
+                {if $customField.type == 'Date'}
+                <td>{$customField.value|crmDate}</td>
+                {else}
                 <td>{$customField.value}</td>
+                {/if}
               </tr>
             {/foreach}
           {/foreach}
```